# Swift - Getting 26 errors when bridging to objective-c

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a project that uses Parse. The parse framework and the other required frameworks are included. This is a pic of the errors I'm getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJLd8.png
In didfinishLaunchingWithOptions in my app delegate I set up my applicationId and clientKey by doing this:

```
Parse.setApplicationId("QuU0D74lukFBkO2Dmg4VN4zkoKiWDjxAjilcIP38",
            clientKey: "vLK6KmpxnM9bPpj5QaqxoqAmW1JIxTYbidxhx2Sp")
```

After that was setup I created an Object to test it. Here is how I did it.

```
var testObject = PFObject(className:"TestObject")
testObject["foo"] = "bar"
testObject.save()
```

`testObject.saveInBackground` does not work because it says "PFObject does not have a member named saveInBackground" so I just did `testObject.save`

I have also tried this:

```
var score = PFObject(className: "score")
score.setObject("Alex", forKey: "name")
score.setObject(95, forKey: "number")
score.save()
```

This also brings up 26 error:

```
var testObject = PFObject(className:"TestObject")
testObject["foo"] = "bar"
testObject["Alex"] = "name"
testObject.save()
```

Comment: Looks like you need to link with `libsqlite3` and the [bolts framework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS). And anything else listed in the [quickstart for the Parse iOS framework](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing)

Comment: I have the libz framework but not bolts maybe that will fix it? Will get back to you on that. @SantaClaus

Comment: You need everything in the instructions [here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing). `libz` is not the same as `libsqlite3`. You need both.

Comment: Thank You! I was following a tutorial and they didnt include libsqlite3 Post an answer and ill give you the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with the frameworks and libraries described in [the quickstart](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing).

> Click the + button in the bottom left of the 'Link Binary With
>   Libraries' section and add the following libraries:
>
> - AudioToolbox.framework
> - CFNetwork.framework
> - CoreGraphics.framework
> - CoreLocation.framework
> - MobileCoreServices.framework
> - QuartzCore.framework
> - Security.framework
> - StoreKit.framework
> - SystemConfiguration.framework
> - libz.dylib
> - libsqlite3.dylib

You also need to link `Bolts.framework` which should have been included with the framework download.